# How to display a flash message along with redirect without using Session in laravel?

Tags: laravel, session

I have a part of code which checks for the file uploaded by user. If I find that is file is not a valid png/jpg/jpeg file then I am deactivating the user and logging him out from the site and deleting his session and then redirecting him to login page. I want to display the error to him that he/she is trying to upload an invalid file. I am not able to find anything on how to display it without using Session.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `return redirect()->route('whatever_route')->withErrors('whatever_the_error');`

Comment: @TharakaDilshan I tried this but this isn't working. I think this also stores the errors in Session, and if thats the case then it will be flushed as I am deleting the Session.

Comment: One thing is Laravel session (the Laravel cookie), and other thing is the authenticate session (the login). When you logout a user, the Laravel session still present and you can use the error bag. If you want to remove the Laravel Session for some reason, you need to create a view for the error, or send your own error variable to de view.

Comment: @Clemen can you give me an example of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new session messages after flush the session, these messages will delete after shown

**controller**

```
$is_valid // boolean 

if(!is_valid) {
// if file is not valid, do something
 ...
// clear all session
session()->flush()
// redirect user to login page and send session message
return redirect()->route("login")
                 ->with("message","Your file is not valid")
                 ->with("message_type","danger");
```

**login.blade**

```
@if(session()->has("message"))
<div class="alert alert-{{session("message_type")}}">
  <p> {{session("message")}} </p>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks I used this and it worked for me. First I was redirecting it to logout url, now instead I am deleting the session there itself and redirecting it to login page with errors

Comment: it worked for me but we need to have login defined in routes

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you don't want to use session for some reason, this is a simple code to show the error message in a specific view and then we give to the user a link to login again.

**UploadController.php**

```
public function myUpload(){

  //... some stuff and then logout the user, delete the session

  return view('uploadError', ['uploadError' => 'for some reason...']);
}
```

**uploadError.blade.php**

```
Error uploading the file: {{ $uploadError }}

<a href="/login">Login again</a>
```

In your case, you can't use the error sessions system because when you delete it, in this moment the user haven't a session, and the response has not session. And if you redirect to the login page from the controller, this login request will generate the new session, not before.

Comment: I tried Hasan's method and it worked for me, so I haven't tried this for now. Thank you for your help. :)